# NSKeyedArchiver working on simulator but not actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nskeyedarchiver

I cannot seem to get `NSKeyedArchiver` working. I have a main `ViewController`, which has an `NSMutableArray` as an instance variable. The array is populated by multiple instances of a custom class. The custom class conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol and implements both the encoding and decoding methods. From the main view controller, I call

```
- (NSString *)itemArchivePath
{
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//only one document in list - get path t o it
NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];

return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"locations.archive"];
}

- (BOOL)saveChanges
{
//returns success or failure
NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];

return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray //this is the array to archive
                                   toFile:path];
}
```

In the app delegate, I call the saveChanges method for applicationDidEnterBackground. The method returns true on the simulator, but false for the actual device. I am not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Based on Zaph's comment, I have changed the saveChanges method to:

```
- (void)saveChanges
{
//returns success or failure
NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];

NSData *dataOfArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
NSFileManager *checker = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[dataOfArray writeToFile:path
              atomically:YES];

if ([checker fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSLog(@"Archive Successful");

}
else {
    NSLog(@"Archive Did Not Work");
}

}
```

Comment: Simulator is not case sensitive but actual devices. So check spelling of "locations.archive".

Comment: I am creating the file locations.archive in the return statement. Every time I refer to the path, I call itemArchivePath, so I never actually type locations.archive other than the first time. I cannot figure out where the spelling of the file might differ.

Comment: Try the archive in two steps to determine if it is an archive or write problem. First use: `archivedDataWithRootObject:` and if successful write with `writeToFile:path atomically:`

Comment: @Zaph Thank you so far! Please check my edits. I am still having a problem with the code.

Comment: Simplify the problem. You are combining things, saving/restoring and `applicationDidEnterBackground`. First get it to work in the foreground, save and immediately restore, get that to work. Check to see if the file gets written on the device, there is no check for that in the latest code.

Comment: I edited the code again (please see above). When running the code, the archive is apparently not working.

Comment: You might have to use `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to create a correct path (should use this method when dealing with paths anyway).

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangSchreurs ! That was the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog the path! It is probably wrong as @Wolfgang states.

```
[documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"locations.archive"]
```

will not add a "/" between the path and filename. use:

```
[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locations.archive"]
```

When code does not work make it as simple as possible, break up compound statements into individual statements. Then follow along with the debugger and/or `NSLog()` statements checking every step.

Comment: Thanks! I checked with the NSLog, and it was the path issue. I was missing the "/" in between the path and locations.archive